# How to select a nested item of json datatype?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-json

I have a MySQL table named `computers` with a column named `details` that is json data type formatted. I've inserted a value like this in that column:

```
'{ "name": "Chrome", "os": "Windows", "resolution": { "x": 1680, "y": 1050 } }'
```

I can simple get `Chrome` value by the following query:

```
SELECT details ->> '$.name' FROM computers
```

Now I want to know, how can I get `1680` value (which is the value of `x`) ?

Comment: While it is possible to query within json data, you'll find it's awkward and possibly the singled slowest thing you can do in your database. You'll do **SO MUCH BETTER** if you update your schema and extract the relevant parts of the json data into dedicated columns as part of the INSERT/UPDATE process.

Comment: Yeah right @JoelCoehoorn thakns. I just wanted to know the syntax

Comment: If you need to work with JSON in MySQL, I recommend you read the documentation and examples in the manual: [JSON data type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json.html) and [JSON functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-functions.html), and practice them. That will answer most of your questions more fully and more quickly than asking on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can alter your query to:

```
SELECT details ->> '$.resolution.x' AS details FROM computers
```

Or use `JSON_EXTRACT`:

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(details, '$.resolution.x') AS details FROM computers
```

**Result:**

```
| details  |
|----------|
| 1680     |
```

Fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/j9VpsVQy).

**Note:** As mentioned above, its not good practice to store information you plan on retrieving in a `JSON` column, create a dedicated value to store this information.